# Javascript not accessing value in form

Tags: javascript, forms, xhtml

I'm learning javascript and xhtml for the first time at the moment and I currently have a problem which I have not been able to solve. I think it's a fairly simple fix, I just don't have to knowledge to be able to do it. Here's the javascript and how I'm attempting to call it from the xhtml.

This is in a javascript file called greet.js.

```
function tOD() {
timeOfDay = new Date
if (timeOfDay.getHours() < 5) {
    alert("Either go to bed, or go back to bed " + document.form[0].inputname.value);
}
else if (timeOfDay.getHours() < 11) {
    alert("Rise and shine " + document.form[0].inputname.value);
}
else if (timeOfDay.getHours() < 17) {
    alert("Good afternoon " document.form[0].inputname.value);
}
else {
    alert("And after a hard day at work you can relax at last, " +  document.form[0].inputname.value);
}
}
```

And here is where I'm trying to implement it in my xhtml.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="greet.js"></script>
<FORM NAME = input>
Please enter your name:
<input type= "text" name = "inputName"/>
<input Type= Button NAME= "greeting" VALUE="ok" onClick="greet()"/>
</FORM>
```

The javascript works in that if I take away document.form[0].inputname.value it'll alert with the correct time of day when I press the button. So it must be the         document.form[0].inputname.value, this must be wrong, I'm just unsure how to fix it. I've also tried using elements[0] instead of form[0] and also input and element[input] so I'm not sure what it could be...

Thanks, all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some errors, I have made a working version for you. Please read it slowly and try to see your errors and fix them ;)

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/3U5Qm/

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot that was extremely helpful, I see where I went wrong now.

Answer (score 2):

Your input

```
<input type="text" name="inputName"/>
```

is "camelCased", meaning the the N in 'name' is uppercase. You are using lowercase name attribute in your JavaScript

```
document.forms[0].inputname.value
```

`inputname` should be `inputName`. Notice that the forms collection is called `document.forms` and not `document.form`!

Besides this, you might want to use an ID on your input, so you could just access it using `document.getElementById('inputid');`

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (timeOfDay.getHours() < 17) {
    alert("Good afternoon " document.form[0].inputname.value);
```

you are missing a + sign

```
else if (timeOfDay.getHours() < 17) {
        alert("Good afternoon " + document.form[0].inputname.value);
```

Comment: it should also be document.forms[0] not document.form[0]